# What was Superman wrong about when he confronted Bruce the second time, in the movie Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

When Superman was forced to fight Batman by Luthor, he made his way to Gotham conflicted on whether he wanted to kill the Bat or appeal to him and ask for his help.

Superman made the sensible choice and decides to come clean to Bruce and he starts with "Bruce, I was wrong, you have to listen to me..."
Now, what did Superman mean he said he was "wrong"? What was he wrong about that he made aware to Batman earlier in the film?

Personally, I think Clark somehow figured out Lex was behind the whole prison stabbings of branded criminals thing, which only provoked Superman the first time to confront the Bat. However, this was never really explained and I was just wondering if there was an explanation in the film about this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Superman's apology is a callback to their last meeting, where Superman rips open the Batmobile and levels an ultimatum at Batman, "Next time they shine your light in the sky, don't go to it. The Bat is dead. Bury it. Consider this mercy."

However, having just been on the receiving end of Lex Luthor's ultimatum- "To save Martha, bring me the head of the Bat."- Superman realizes how he's wronged Batman:  Judging him from afar, on incomplete information, whilst lording his power over him, acting as judge, jury, or god, such that his sentence may be called "mercy."

Instead of threatening the Bat, Superman needs the Bat- "I have to go to Gotham
to convince him to help me."- so he's taking back his last interaction with Batman.  "I was wrong."

Comment: So superman was kinda hypocritical, as he himself was acting as this judge and jury while calling out the bat. Although what I don't get is how does the statement "To save Martha, bring me the head of the Bat." makes superman realize, he was "wrong" about him? Lex could have said, "To save Martha, bring me the head of the president."...would it make a difference?  I understand superman was maybe judging batman out of his ignorance and simply confronted him initially out of pure emotion. I guess he feels a little hypocritical henceforth, but how exactly he knew "wrong" he was wrong?

Comment: It's not the phrase but the situation. If Batman is an unchecked vigilante, then Superman justifies his ultimatum as a necessary means (retire the Bat only).  However, once he's on the receiving end... if Superman is an unchecked power, then Lex justifies his ultimatum as a necessary means (sully Superman only).  Just because you have power / ability / justifications doesn't make ultimatums the right approach.  He could have conversed instead of strong armed. "Good is a conversation."  Once on the receiving end he clearly sees his prior approach to Batman was wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see. Now that Superman steps into Batman's shoes he sees himself in Lex as he was giving him the ultimatum as he did to the Bat. In this regard, he was wrong about himself, which makes perfect sense. Also with Clark being ignorant of the whole branding situation and similarly how both Lex and Batman are ignorant of superman and his heroism. He decides to bury this hatchet and decides to ask batman's help and trusts him with Martha's rescue. Is that what's happening?